# Monitor a file on linux

Tags: linux, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File audit in Linux: how to watch directory tree for deletions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/144698/file-audit-in-linux-how-to-watch-directory-tree-for-deletions)
>   [Find out which process is changing a file](https://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file)

In linux is there a command where it can say who are all the users who have accessed one partic

stat command just gives me the basic

Is there a utility where i can list of all the users or how to know the users who have done those changes

or how can a file be monitored and log these information

Comment: in short: you want to know who's access a file ? -- try process accounting, command logging, version control, lsof, or similar. Amongst that lot there's prolly something that'll help you. It sounds like you want revision control though - see "svn". If you just want to know when the file is changed, use iwatch or similar.

Comment: No not exactly ,At some point of time just want to know who are all the users who have accessed the scripts and executed it..Kind of logging system

Answer (score 1):

You can try audit. [This link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) provide information related to Centos/redhat, but it should be similar for other distributions also.