# CentOS 6 deleting files from /root/ after a reboot?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, root

Twice recently I've noticed that my vim settings have changed to defaults.  Investigation shows that all files have been deleted from my /root/ directory.  (Yes I currently log in as root, that's a different conversation...)

Can anyone suggest why this would be happening?  The first time I assumed I'd accidentally repeated a recent command from my bash history as I had done an `rm -f` in a different folder shortly before hand, but on this occasion I've not `rm`'d anything for days and after a yum update (which included a new kernel) and a reboot the files have gone again...?

Folders don't get deleted from /root/, just files.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/144698/file-audit-in-linux-how-to-watch-directory-tree-for-deletions

Comment: I've figured mine out.  I have a cron bash script that runs every minute.  It cd's to a cache directory of my website, and deletes any files older then 5 minutes.  Sometimes after a reboot that directory doesn't exist, in which case it deletes any files older than 5 minutes in my home directory.  Adding a check that the directory exists is all that was needed!